# DirectX Texture Not Drawing Correctly

Tags: c++, graphics, directx, textures, directx-11

I'm trying to render a texture to the screen using DirectX **without** DirectXTK.

This is the texture that I am trying to render on screen (512x512px):

[image]

The texture loads correctly but when it is put on the screen, it comes up like this:

[image: Screenshot of rendered texture]

I noticed that the rendered image seems to be the texture split four times in the x-direction and many times in the y-direction. The tiles seem to increase in height as the texture is rendered farther down the screen.

I have two thoughts as to how the texture was rendered incorrectly.

- I could have initialized the texture incorrectly.
- I could have improperly setup my texture sampler.

---

Regarding improper texture initialization, here is the code that I used to initialize the texture.

**Texture2D & Shader Resource View Creation Code**

**Load Texture Data**

This loads the texture for a PNG file into a vector of unsigned chars and sets the width and height of the texture.

```
std::vector<unsigned char> fileData;
if (!loadFileToBuffer(fileName, fileData))
    return nullptr;
std::vector<unsigned char> imageData;
unsigned long width;
unsigned long height;
decodePNG(imageData, width, height, fileData.data(), fileData.size());
```

**Create Texture Description**

```
D3D11_TEXTURE2D_DESC texDesc;
ZeroMemory(&texDesc, sizeof(D3D11_TEXTURE2D_DESC));
texDesc.Width = width;
texDesc.Height = height;
texDesc.MipLevels = 1;
texDesc.ArraySize = 1;
texDesc.Format = DXGI_FORMAT_R8G8B8A8_UNORM;
texDesc.SampleDesc.Count = 1;
texDesc.SampleDesc.Quality = 0;
texDesc.Usage = D3D11_USAGE_DYNAMIC;
texDesc.BindFlags = D3D11_BIND_SHADER_RESOURCE;
texDesc.CPUAccessFlags = D3D10_CPU_ACCESS_WRITE;
```

**Assign Texture Subresource Data**

```
D3D11_SUBRESOURCE_DATA texData;
ZeroMemory(&texData, sizeof(D3D11_SUBRESOURCE_DATA));
texData.pSysMem = (void*)imageData.data();
texData.SysMemPitch = sizeof(unsigned char) * width;

//Create DirectX Texture In The Cache
HR(m_pDevice->CreateTexture2D(&texDesc, &texData, &m_textures[fileName]));
```

**Create Shader Resource View for Texture**

```
D3D11_SHADER_RESOURCE_VIEW_DESC srDesc;
ZeroMemory(&srDesc, sizeof(D3D11_SHADER_RESOURCE_VIEW_DESC));
srDesc.Format = DXGI_FORMAT_R8G8B8A8_UNORM;
srDesc.ViewDimension = D3D11_SRV_DIMENSION_TEXTURE2D;
srDesc.Texture2D.MipLevels = 1;

HR(m_pDevice->CreateShaderResourceView(m_textures[fileName], &srDesc,
    &m_resourceViews[fileName]));
return m_resourceViews[fileName];//This return value is used as "texture" in the next line
```

**Use The Texture Resource**

```
m_pDeviceContext->PSSetShaderResources(0, 1, &texture);
```

I have messed around with the MipLevels and SampleDesc.Quality variables to see if they were changing something about the texture but changing them either made the texture black or did nothing to change it.

I also looked into the the SysMemPitch variable and made sure that it aligned with [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff476220(v=vs.85).aspx)

---

Regarding setting up my sampler incorrectly, here is the code that I used to initialize my sampler.

```
//Setup Sampler
D3D11_SAMPLER_DESC samplerDesc;
ZeroMemory(&samplerDesc, sizeof(D3D11_SAMPLER_DESC));

samplerDesc.Filter = D3D11_FILTER_MIN_MAG_MIP_LINEAR;
samplerDesc.AddressU = D3D11_TEXTURE_ADDRESS_CLAMP;
samplerDesc.AddressV = D3D11_TEXTURE_ADDRESS_CLAMP;
samplerDesc.AddressW = D3D11_TEXTURE_ADDRESS_CLAMP;
samplerDesc.MipLODBias = 0.0f;
samplerDesc.MaxAnisotropy = 1;
samplerDesc.ComparisonFunc = D3D11_COMPARISON_NEVER;
samplerDesc.BorderColor[0] = 1.0f;
samplerDesc.BorderColor[1] = 1.0f;
samplerDesc.BorderColor[2] = 1.0f;
samplerDesc.BorderColor[3] = 1.0f;
samplerDesc.MinLOD = -FLT_MAX;
samplerDesc.MaxLOD = FLT_MAX;

HR(m_pDevice->CreateSamplerState(&samplerDesc, &m_pSamplerState));

//Use the sampler
m_pDeviceContext->PSSetSamplers(0, 1, &m_pSamplerState);
```

I have tried different AddressU/V/W types to see if the texture was loaded with incorrect width/height and was thus shrunk but changing these did nothing.

---

My VertexShader passes the texture coordinates through using `TEXCOORD0` and my PixelShader uses `texture.Sample(samplerState, input.texCoord);` to get the color of the pixel.

---

In summary, I am trying to render a texture but the texture gets tiled and I am not able to figure out why. What do I need to change/do to render just one of my texture?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you assign the wrong pitch:

```
texData.SysMemPitch = sizeof(unsigned char) * width;
```

should be

```
texData.SysMemPitch = 4 * sizeof(unsigned char) * width;
```

because each pixels has `DXGI_FORMAT_R8G8B8A8_UNORM` format and occupies 4 bytes.

Comment: See [DirectX Tool Kit](https://github.com/Microsoft/DirectXTK) for some extensive example code for loading textures and the like.